# Add an existing view with a nib file in another view through Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have a nib file say TestView.xib. I added some components to it.

Now I created another nib file AnotherTestView.xib

I want to add the view of TestView.xib into AnotherTestView.xib using interface buidler, so that I dont need to add the same components from TestView again. They are like basic components for all my views.

Is there any way to do that. Like can we set the nib file name for a UIView in IB. Or how can we add this existing view which has a nib file into another nib file.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem I'm having. Stuck and totally lost!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up how we [embed custom-view Nibs inside other Nibs](http://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142) in a longish blog post. The crux is overriding `-awakeAfterUsingCoder:` in your custom view, replacing the object loaded from AnotherTextView.xib with the one loaded from the "embedded" Nib (TestView.xib).

Something along these lines:

```
// TestView.m
- (id) awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    BOOL theThingThatGotLoadedWasJustAPlaceholder = ([[self subviews] count] == 0);
    if (theThingThatGotLoadedWasJustAPlaceholder) {
        // load the embedded view from its Nib
        TestView* theRealThing = nil;
        NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: NSStringFromClass([TestView class])
                                                          owner: nil
                                                        options: nil];
        for (id anObject in elements) {
            if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[TestView class]]) {
                theRealThing = anObject;
                break;
            }
        }

        // pass properties through
        theRealThing.frame = self.frame;
        theRealThing.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;

        [self release];
        self = [theRealThing retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```